# Задача javaScript (не могу решить)

Tags: javascript

Моя цель решить задачу по JS, задача об 2х отделах продажи

```
1. Создать стрелочную функцию getAVG для вычисления среднего объема продаж за месяц в квартале.
2. Использовать функцию getAVG для вычисления среднего значения для каждого отдела.
3. Создайте функцию Bonus, которая принимает среднее значение
продажи каждого отдела в качестве параметров: `Bonus` (`dept1AVGSales`, `dept2AVGSales`). 
Если продажи одного отдела как минимум на 30% выше, 
чем другого, функция должна рассчитать бонус для победителя
в процентах от этой разницы и вывести это в консоль.
Например, если продажи отдела 1 на 35% больше, 
функция должна вывести в консоль следующее сообщение: 
"Отдел 1 получит бонус в размере 35%". Аналогично 2ой отдел продаж
4. Если продажи одного отдела больше чем продажи другого меньше чем на 30 % то вывести в консоль - `No bonuses for this quarter`
5. Использовать функцию Bonus с двумя наборами данных:

 First quartal
       | January| February| March |
 dept 1| 35467  | 29842   | 38501 |
 dept 2| 70533  | 50121   | 33899|

 Second quartal

       | April  | May     | June  |
 dept 1| 50301  | 21984   | 19207 |
 dept 2| 72381  | 41562   | 29465 |

 if a > b
 c = a - b
 p = c / b * 100
```

Вот как пытался решить ...

```
/* The first quartal */
const dept1AVGSales1 = getAVG(35467, 29842, 38501)
const dept2AVGSales1 = getAVG(70533, 50121, 33899)
console.log(dept1AVGSales1, dept2AVGSales1);

/* The second quartal */
const dept1AVGSales2 = getAVG(50301, 21984, 19207)
const dept2AVGSales2 = getAVG(72381, 41562, 29465)
console.log(dept1AVGSales2, dept2AVGSales2);

// bonus
const Bonus = function (dept1AVGSales, dept2AVGSales) {
    if (dept1AVGSales > dept2AVGSales){
        const diff = dept1AVGSales - dept2AVGSales
        const procent = diff / dept2AVGSales * 100;
        if (procent >= 30) {
            console.log(`departament 1 will get a bonus of ${procent}`)
        } else {
            console.log('No bonus in this quartal');
        }
    }//
}
Bonus(dept1AVGSales1, dept2AVGSales1);
Bonus(dept1AVGSales2, dept2AVGSales2);
```

Comment: не нужно дублировать вопрос. Достаточно отредактировать исходный

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hx1zk95c/

Comment: Так бонус должен высчитывать для 3х унииверсальных чисел, вывести в средне арифметическое число